# How to get string resource id from jni?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

From within JNI, how do I get string resource id?
For instance, in Java it looks like

```
final int langId = R.string.LANGUAGE;
```

There is auto-generated R.java:

```
package com.my.game;

...

public final class R {
    ...
    public static final class string {
        public static int LANGUAGE=0x7f06001c;
        ...
    }
...
}
```

I tried

```
jclass rcl = jni_env->FindClass("com.my.game.R.string");
assert(rcl);
jfieldID fid = jni_env->GetFieldID(rcl, "LANGUAGE", "(I)");
assert(fid);
int langId = jni_env->GetStaticIntField(rcl, fid);
```

but the first assert (`assert(rcl)`) fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three problems in your code:

First, the `string` class is nested inside `com.my.game.R`. To access it via JNI, you have to write it like this:

```
com.my.game.R$string
```

The second problem: The field is static, so you must use `GetStaticFieldID` instead of `GetFieldID`.

And finally, `GetFieldID` wants a field signature. A field is not a method, so the parentheses are wrong here. The field signature is just `I`.